# Склонение фамилии Горец

Tags: склонение, склонение-фамилий

Как склонять фамилию Гóрец по падежам для женского и мужского рода?

Comment: Для женского рода не склоняется, а для мужского - склонение такое же, как у одноимённого  существительного.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Склонение фамилий на **-ец** зависит от пола лица. Если фамилия относится к мужчине, то она склоняется как существительное второго склонения мужского рода.
Женские фамилии такого типа не склоняются.

При склонения мужских фамилий, оканчивающихся на **-ец**, часто возникает вопрос: сохранять ли беглый гласный? Вот что рекомендует [Грамота](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%B6%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B8).

Вопрос № 287409 (фамилия ***Розумец***)
Ответ. Мужская фамилия склоняется, женская нет. Возможно склонение мужской фамилии с выпадением гласного (**Розумца, Розумцу**) и без выпадения гласного (**Розумеца, Розумецу**). Второй вариант предпочтителен (ведь фамилии выполняют и юридическую функцию), но окончательное решение — за носителем фамилии.

Вопрос № 285004 (фамилия ***Пирожок***)
Ответ. Мужскую фамилию Пирожок надо склонять, женская фамилия не склоняется. Возможно склонение мужской фамилии с выпадением гласного (**Пирожка, Пирожку**) и без выпадения гласного (**Пирожока, Пирожоку**). Второй вариант предпочтителен (чтобы отделить фамилию от **омонимичного нарицательного существительного**), но окончательное решение — за носителем фамилии.

Получается, что возможны два варианта.
Гóрец — Гóрца, Гóрцу, Гóрцем, о Гóрце; Гóреца, Гóрецу, Гóрецем, о Гóреце.

В моей практике встречались фамилии Дворец и Самец — я предпочитала их склонять без выпадения гласного (Дворецу, Самецу).

[Как склонять фамилии (трудные случаи)](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/71-rubric-482)
[Фамилии на согласный звук](http://www.oshibok-net.ru/for-all/sklonenie-famili/skl-na-sogl/)